# Load all the Contacts from iphone PhoneBook in a variable

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, abaddressbook

I am naive to the xcode programming. I need to load all the contacts from the iPhone PhoneBook on a variable.

Could you please suggest me some library or something like that. Any sample code would be highly appreciable.

Looking forward to a response.:)

Thanks in advance!!..... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all after a long fight I found the following code working

```
    self.dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // dataSouce is delared in .h file

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
NSMutableArray *allPeople = (NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook); 
int nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); 

for(int i=0; i < nPeople; i++ ){
    ABRecordRef person = [allPeople objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *name = @"";
    if(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) != NULL)
        name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    [dataSource addObject: name];
}
```