# adding contacts to my table view ,

Tags: iphone, uitableview, contacts, abaddressbook

I have an import button and clicking that shows a contacts view. Then, from here I want to select the required contact name and add to my table view.

Comment: please post your questions clearly and try to accept the answers also..

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Address Book Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) to start with - it includes a quick start tutorial for what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can look [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883248/load-all-the-contacts-from-iphone-phonebook-in-a-variable) that deals with loading the contacts in a variable. That varaible could be used as the Datasource of your table. :)